Can I lock a Texture's placement on a Grease Pencil Stroke?
If I create a stroke with the grease pencil of a large radius (say 100), and then apply a texture to the material, and adjust the UV Factor, I can get an image that follows down the length of the stroke.
But then when I rotate my camera around the stroke, the texture is locked to the camera view, always facing my camera wherever I rotate it to, almost like the stroke is made up of facing cards.
Is there a way to lock the texture so it looks like more how a texture would be applied to a cylinder, where it's locked to U and V, not just V?
Video of what I mean

Hello and welcome. Can you show some screenshots of what you mean?
